# Discord bot v14 discord presence/status not showing or working

Tags: node.js, discord

How can i fix this issue?
And can anybody fix this?

Here's the code:

```
if (config.BotActivitySettings && config.BotActivitySettings.Enabled) {
    let activType;
    if (config.BotActivitySettings.Type === "WATCHING") activType = Discord.ActivityType.Watching;
    else if (config.BotActivitySettings.Type === "PLAYING") activType = Discord.ActivityType.Playing;
    else if (config.BotActivitySettings.Type === "COMPETING") activType = Discord.ActivityType.Competing;
    else {
      console.error("Invalid activity type specified in the configuration.");
      return;
    }
    if (Array.isArray(config.BotActivitySettings.Statuses) && config.BotActivitySettings.Statuses.length > 0) {
      let index = 0;
      client.user.setActivity(getActivityText(), { type: activType });
      setInterval(() => {
        index = (index + 1) % config.BotActivitySettings.Statuses.length;
        client.user.setActivity(getActivityText(), { type: activType });
      }, config.BotActivitySettings.Interval * 1000);
    } else {
      console.error("Invalid or empty array for statuses in the configuration.");
      return;
    }
    function getActivityText() {
      return config.BotActivitySettings.Statuses[index]
        .replace(/{total-users}/g, `${guild.memberCount}`)
        .replace(/{total-channels}/g, `${client.channels.cache.size}`)
        .replace(/{total-messages}/g, `${client.guildData.get(guild.id, 'totalMessages')}`);
    }
  }
```

I've tryed for about 3 hours or longer to fix this issue but nothing has worked.

I've thought that it should work but it actually didn't.

--

---

- 

Comment: Hi! I know you're new to StackOverflow, it would be helpful if you could include more information about the following: What the problem is, is there an error message? What should be happening? What have you already attempted? It will assist in answering your question!